# Step function for EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-step-functions

I am trying to run a Step function workflow to execute an EKS Run job task on existing EKS cluster. The jobs runs fine, however when next time the step function is invoked it fails since the pervious execution job state exists in Kubernetes.

Is there a way to generate job name in step function with timestamp so that we don't have to delete previous execution and the next job also gets triggered.

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "EKS RunJob",
  "States": {
    "EKS RunJob": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::eks:runJob",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterName": "MyClusterName",
        "CertificateAuthority": "LS0tLS1CRUd ... UtLS0tLQo=",
        "Endpoint": "https://12341234.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com",
        "Job": {
          "apiVersion": "batch/v1",
          "kind": "Job",
          "metadata": {
            "name": "Job_name_with_timestamp"
          },
          "spec": {
            "template": {
              "metadata": {
                "name": "Job_name_with_timestamp"
              },
              "spec": {
                "containers": [
                  {
                    "name": "my-function-name",
                    "image": "perl",
                    "command": [
                      "perl"
                    ],
                    "args": [
                      "-Mbignum=bpi",
                      "-wle",
                      "print bpi(2000)"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "restartPolicy": "Never"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html#task-state-fields) field in your [Task state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html) to generate a dynamic name. Your best best is probably to use something like the example below, which uses dynamic fields in the [Context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) to generate a name that will be unique and also helpful to tie back to your [Step Functions workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

This will generate a value for the name field something like `arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789100:execution:MyStateMachine-r3kkw3vg2:1872b558-8220-3bf2-bf01-56d293dbd4c6-EKS RunJob-0`

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "EKS RunJob",
  "States": {
    "EKS RunJob": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::eks:runJob",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterName": "MyClusterName",
        "CertificateAuthority": "LS0tLS1CRUd ... UtLS0tLQo=",
        "Endpoint": "https://12341234.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com",
        "Job": {
          "apiVersion": "batch/v1",
          "kind": "Job",
          "metadata": {
            "name.$": "States.Format('{}-{}-{}',$$.Execution.Id,$$.State.Name,$$.State.RetryCount)"
          },
          "spec": {
            "template": {
              "metadata": {
                "name": "Job_name_with_timestamp"
              },
              "spec": {
                "containers": [
                  {
                    "name": "my-function-name",
                    "image": "perl",
                    "command": [
                      "perl"
                    ],
                    "args": [
                      "-Mbignum=bpi",
                      "-wle",
                      "print bpi(2000)"
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "restartPolicy": "Never"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a limitation of 63 characters for the name and there is a possibility that the execution can be triggered multiple time so it is not a retry. I would end up with the same name. So was trying $$.Execution.StartTime but this too is giving the output in upper case which is causing an error.

Comment: The ExecutionID is unique for Standard Workflows for a period of 90 days. If you need a shorter name and want to avoid capitals, then you might do something like this: `"name.$": "States.Format('{}-{}-{}',States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.Execution.Id, ':'), 7),'runjob1',$$.State.RetryCount)"`

Comment: Or just generate a straight up new GUID each time: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-uuid-generate

Comment: yes I am using uid to get that unique combination as of now